# What is the best way to model the database here. Polymorphism or STI? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three types of `Hangout`s: `Home`, `Bar`, `Restaurant`. What's a good way to model these three hangouts?

I am trying to model an airbnb like app where customers can rent or share hangouts. A home,  bar, restaurant, and possibly more types of hangouta in the future are all open for sharing.

Is this a decent way to model this using polymorphism?

```
class Hangout < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hangoutable, polymorphic: true
end

class Home < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :hangout, as: :hangoutable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :hangout, as: :hangoutable, dependent: :destroy
end

...
```

The idea here is that the parent model is a `Hangout` which could be one of the three `hangoutables`. Is this correct? Complaints about this is that it's kind of inverted... Each `Hangout` has one `hangout`, but the hangout is supposed to be the parent, not the child as it is modeled here. Is this okay? Will this cause me problems down the line? Usually polymorphism is done with the polymorphic entity as the child (e.g. `imageable` belongs to a person, a place, a thing, etc.) but here I want `Hangout` to be the parent.

The underlying table for hangout would look like this:

```
 create_table "hangouts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "hangoutable_type"
    t.bigint "hangoutable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["hangoutable_type", "hangoutable_id"], name: "index_hangouts_on_hangoutable_type_and_hangoutable_id"
  end
```

STI was also suggested to me but after reading [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2) I'm not sure if these tables will share the same data in the future. So I am hesitant to use STI.

What can I do?

Comment: You've described your imagined associations between the models, but the only clue about how they're actually related is in the names. With only that information, this model doesn't make much sense to me: what columns are going to be on each of these tables? Why does `hangouts` need to exist? It sounds more like STI than polymorphism to me, but I think you need to describe more about the data you need to store.

Comment: like @matthewd alluded to, if they all act similarly, it's probably STI. You could merely have a `Hangout` model with a `type` of either `Bar`, `Restaurant`, or `Home`

Comment: I edited it a bit. a hangout needs to exist because in my mind it's easier to have a parent entity like hangout because it can have an associated address or pictures and a hangout is created of various types.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Hangout model *only* -- with e.g. an enum to distinguish Bar, Restaurant, etc.

If they turn out to have significant behavioural differences, you could convert them to STI later. (Or even, if you want to make life needlessly difficult, the approximation of Class Table Inheritance you've described above.)

But in the short term, you're going to be best served by having them all live in one table, and implemented by a single class. 95% of your functionality is going to be treating all hangouts as equivalent; the fact they get different UI icons (say) is not necessarily a class-level distinction.

Do not be too quick to create separate model classes for every noun in your domain: classes separate *implemented behaviour* only. Introduce more when there's weight for them to pull, and not before.

Comment: I feel like this is a known anti-pattern, often attributed to inheritance examples like `Dog < Animal`.. but can't think of its name

Comment: Dont classes and tables separate different data too?

Comment: Yes, and that's the point: this data is not substantively different -- in a way that matters to the application -- just as you wouldn't create separate models/tables for users based on which country they live in. It's an attribute, not a fundamental behavioural distinction.

Comment: But what if restaurants and bars have different data to be stored? Like different data attributes?

Comment: Add extra [optional] columns, and then choose between conditional validations or STI. Again, for your purposes, a restaurant and a bar are _really_ similar.

Comment: STI is the same table though right? So having extra columns in this table that only some of the types use is kind of a problem right?